# catching exceptions in ML

Tags: sml, smlnj

is it possible in ML catch every possible exception? for example if I don't know what exception might be

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `handle` statement lets you pattern match exceptions, so you can use something like `handle _` to match anything, e.g.

```
hd [] handle _ => 0
```